# getting MCC,MNC,LAC,Cell ID) details from a sms

Tags: android, mobile

i am thinking whether it is possible to get information related to following items form the sms message coming from a mobile.....

- Mobile Country Code (MCC)
- Mobile Network Code (MNC)
- Local Area Code(LAC)
- Cell ID

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the MCC/MNC of the sender, the answer is: No. As this information isn't transmitted within an SMS message, there's no way for Android to access it. Keep in mind that SMS messages don't necessarily originate from a mobile phone anyway. If you are asking about the receiver, then yes, that information [is available to you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html).